# Looking for a particular reciter of Qur'an

Tags: quran-recitation

I had the mp3 formats of some surahs from Juz A'mma in my SD-card, but I lost them all. His recitation style was different from most of the others: at some of those recordings, he had recited 2 short surahs immediately, without breaking in between as is usual. For example, he recited (if I remember correctly) surah Nasr immediately after al-Kafirun. He would not elongate. I looked for his audio recordings on the Web but haven't found any. 
Do you know of such a reciter? (Or any suggestions)
If you do, could you please provide the link?

Comment: I seriously doubt that someone will be able to help from the given information. SInce you should the reciter's recognize, maybe you can go through a set of several different recordings of reciters and try to find it.

Comment: @UmH Assalamu a'laykum! I did go through several recordings (more than 100) but couldn't find that recitation.

Comment: What you are looking for seems to me hardly on-topic as it is not a question about Islam and its teaching.

Answer (score 2):

it's hard to any one to know who is the reciter but from what you say(he had recited 2 short surahs immediately, without breaking in between as is usual) this mean it maybe half an hamza's a novel 
you can find the reciter  who read using this novel in this link 
http://ar.assabile.com/quran/collections/all/khalaf-a-n-hamzah

and i suggest to you this reciter 
http://ar.assabile.com/abdul-rashid-ali-sufi-26/collection/al-mus-haf-al-murattal-260